# Sidebar on HTML responsive disappears on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a website coded with HTML responsive and the sidebar navigator element of the site disappears on mobile. The following is what I currently have in terms of code for this. I would like to have the sidebar work on mobile, would be grateful to anyone who can help.

```
            <header id="header" class="skel-layers-fixed">
            <img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="" style="width:64px;height:48px;border:50;">
                <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="platform.html">Platform</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="endorsements.html">Endorsements</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: you mean the menu doesn't appear in mobile?

Comment: Yes, new to html sorry.

Comment: Show css also so we can see what you are doing in it

Comment: lol, I've check your site  on mobile size, you can see your menu on the upper left corner of your site.... are you the one who made it?

Comment: Use Bootstrap for better responsiveness.It provides you inbuilt classes so there will be no fuzzyness in code.

Answer (score 0):

Your nav-element is inside your header-element. That means, that perhaps, depending on your CSS-styling, your nav-element can be hidden behind the image. Start by inspecting your source-code in the browser and se if it even generates correctly. Then go on from there... Try also to avoid inline-css-styling, by experience this can mess up your workflow and makes it harder to debugging, and for other to understand and read your code.